# How to get hats

Tags: support, winter-bash

I tried to get some of the hat achievements, like voting on meta or updating more than 2 item of developer story, but nothing happens.

Is there a delay for the hat achievement to be validated?

Comment: You already have two hats on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1278479/soufiane-ghzal?tab=topactivity#winter-bash) what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hats are awarded by a script that runs every 10 minutes, so you might need to wait a little bit longer. So there is a delay but not a large one, like with some of the badges.